# WPF updating ListBox items from method called in different class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have been banging my head against WPF ListBox item binding for hours and am hoping to get some advice. My application has three main elements:

1. A `Player` class that sends and receives data over a `TcpClient`.
2. A `MainWindow` that handles the GUI and exposes methods that `Player` can call to provide data for updating the UI based on network messages.
3. A `UserControl` called `HostLobby` that contains 1) a `ListBox` called `gamesListBox` for displaying new games as they are added by clients via `Player` and 2) UI elements for adding a new game to be broadcast to all clients.

I have confirmed that the "upstream" piece works. You can enter new game information on `HostLobby`, submit, and it propagates to clients as expected. In addition, clients respond properly to server messages telling them a new game has been added.

The problem is, I cannot get `gameListBox` to update. I rigged up test buttons on both the `HostLobby` control and `MainWindow` to verify that binding is working properly - which it is. I just can't seem to update by passing data from `Player`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Relevant code:

Player.cs

```
public void AddGameToLobby(string name, int mp)
{
    // name and mp are provided by the network message handler and work fine
    WriteToLog("Attempting to add game to host lobby", true);        
    mainWindow.AddGameToLobby(name, mp);    
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public void AddGameToLobby(string n, int mp)
{
    hostLobby.AddGameToList(n, mp);
}
```

HostLobby.cs

```
private MainWindow parent; // used to call an AddGame event when client adds a game
public ObservableCollection<Game> games;
public class Game
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public HostLobby(MainWindow mw)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    parent = mw;
    games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();

    // add some test items - this works. the ListBox updates properly
    games.Add(new Game() { Name = "game1" });
    games.Add(new Game() { Name = "game2" });
    games.Add(new Game() { Name = "game3" });

    gamesListBox.ItemsSource = games;
}
public void AddGameToList(string n, int maxp)
{
    // called to announce a new game added by another client
    // call stack is Player.AddGameToLobby -> MainWindow.AddGameToLobby -> this.AddGameToList
    string msg = String.Format("{0} (0/{1})", n, maxp.ToString());
    games.Add(new Game() { Name = msg });
}
```

HostLobby.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="50" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Width="80">Game Name:</Label>
            <TextBox Name="gameNameTextBox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="200"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Width="80">Max Players:</Label>
            <TextBox Name="maxPlayersTextBox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="200"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Name="addGameButton" Click="addGameButton_Click" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="200" Height="30">Add Game</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label>Current Games</Label>
        <ListBox Name="gamesListBox" MinHeight="200">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that HostLobby's constructor gets a reference to MainWindow so it can call a function on addGameButtonClick when the client wants to add a new game.

Comment: In the line `gamesListView.ItemsSource = games;`, does `gamesListView` somehow correspond to `gamesListBox` in the XAML? Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Sorry about that - editing error. Yes, gamesListView was a typo. Should have been gamesListBox.

Comment: Is the method `AddGameToLobby` in the `Player` class being called on a background thread, by any chance? Observable collections cannot be modified from a background thread if you want the events to be raised properly.

Comment: I don't believe so - is there a way I can check (Visual Studio 2017)? Player does use a networking class to handle TcpClient operations. That class has a GetMessage method that listens for messages asynchronously using NetworkStream.BeginRead. It spawns a thread, but that shouldn't affect Player, right?

Comment: OK, checked the Thread trace and Player is on a worker thread - could that be the problem?

Comment: Yep! I'll write up an official answer on how to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListBox` is not being updated because you're modifying the `ObservableCollection` on a worker thread, which means that the collection's `CollectionChanged` event is being raised on the worker thread as well. To remedy this, you need to modify your list on the UI thread. To achieve this, you have a few options, but the first ones that come to mind are:

**Using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke**

In `AddGameToList` in `HostLobby.cs`, put the statement that modifies the list inside a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

`Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => games.Add(new Game() { Name = msg })));`

**Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization (.NET 4.5 or later)**

First, create a lock object as a private member of your `HostLobby` class. Then, after initializing your `ObservableCollection`, call the following:

`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(games, _yourLockObj);`

Then, use the lock whenever you modify the list within `HostLobby`. So in this instance, you'd want to change the list modification in `AddGameToList` such that it uses the lock:

```
lock (_yourLockObj)
{
    games.Add(new Game() { Name = msg });
}
```

---

The latter seems like a better choice in my opinion, but it is only available if you're using .NET 4.5 or later.